# React fails to compile / function undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new to react, in one of my components i have the following:

```
checkNav() {
        if (this.state.step === 0) {
            this.setState({ nextEnabled: this.state.agreementAccepted });
        } else if (this.state.step === 1) {
            this.setState({ nextEnabled: this.state.privacyPolicyAccepted });
        }
    }

    render() {
>173        checkNav();

        return (
            <div className="first-login-form-content">
                <div className="label">Initial Login Wizard</div>
                {this.initialLoginWizard()}
                <div className="navButtons">
                    <button disabled={!this.state.backEnabled} onClick={this.handleBack}>Back</button>
                    <button disabled={!this.state.nextEnabled} onClick={this.handleNext}>Next</button>
                    <button className="acceptBtn" disabled={!this.state.acceptEnabled} onClick={this.handleAccept}>Accept</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

But this produces the following error for me:

> Failed to compile ./src/components/Login.js   Line 173:  'checkNav' is
>   not defined  no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

what do i need to do so this function gets declared before being called?

Comment: Is the >173 part of the code a typo?   
If it isn't, you might have to remove it, else, you need to declare checkNav as a function.

Comment: function checkNav() {}

Comment: >173 is pointing to the line number. function checkNav() {} gives me "unexpected token" pointing after "function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to run a method of the `class`'s instance you need to access it via the `this` key word:

```
this.checkNav()
```

With that being said, you are calling `setState` inside the `render` method which may lead to an infinite loop. Try moving it to another life-cycle method (`componentDidUpdate`?)

As per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render):

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser.
>
> If you need to interact with the browser, perform your work in componentDidMount() or the other lifecycle methods instead. Keeping render() pure makes components easier to think about.

Comment: thats it! Thanks!

Comment: If that solved your problem, you should thank also by marking question as resolved and with an upvote.